# How to compile project with clang and the option -std=c++11, using autotools

Tags: c++, c, c++11, clang, autotools

I'm developping a software with C and C++ code. I've recently added some code in c++11 standard.
In configure.ac I wrote:

```
for f in '-std=c++11' '-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++'
do
    AX_CHECK_COMPILE_FLAG([$f], [CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS $f" stdpass=true], [], [], [])
${stdpass-false} && break
done
if ! "${stdpass-false}"; then
    AC_MSG_ERROR([Unable to turn on C++11 mode with this compiler])
fi
```

With gcc I've no problem, everything goes well the option -std=c++11 is only applied to g++ and not on gcc.
If I try to configure with:

```
CC=clang ./configure
```

I have the following error:

```
checking whether C compiler accepts -std=c++11... no
checking whether C compiler accepts -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++... no
configure: error: Unable to turn on C++11 mode with this compiler
```

It's like if the option was applied on the C compiler and not only on clang++ (like it's done with gcc).

Can someone help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Check `config.log` to see the actual compilation command, and the resulting error.

Comment: That "checking whether **C** compiler..." message make me think that you forgot [to set the language](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.63/html_node/Language-Choice.html).

Comment: Also, you should be using `CXX=clang++ ./configure` to set the C++ compiler.

Comment: OK, CXX=clang++ ./configure seems to work but only c++ part is compiled with clang++. C part is compile by gcc. If I'm doing: CC=clang CXX=clang++ ./configure It does not work.

Comment: Joachim: It seems that putting both: AC_LANG([C]), AC_LANG([C++]) gives good result !!!
You should write it in the answer part ;)

Thank you

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It seems that putting both: AC_LANG([C]), AC_LANG([C++]) gives good result !!! You should write it in the answer part ;) Thank you

Comment: There is a already a an autoconf macro that checks for C++11
support in the C++ compiler: [AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html).
To use in `configure.ac`, drop it in your project's `m4` directory.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: really good to know. Thank you !!

Comment: @MikeKinghan: On my machine there are no problems. But on some machines (with same version of autoconf and automake), we have the message: ./configure: line 6610: syntax error near unexpected token `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX'
./configure: line 6610: `AX_REQUIRE_DEFINED(AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX)'

Comment: @lock: Needs to be properly introduced, See [6.3.4 Handling Local Macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Local-Macros.html). An `autoreconf` will also suffice for the `aclocal` re-run.

Comment: I've read and done that. I've a m4 folder with files ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4 and ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4 downloaded from website as recommanded. In configure.ac I wrote: AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4]) then: m4_include([m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4]), m4_include([m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4]) and AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11. Of course I also defined AC_LANG([C]) and AC_LANG([C++])

Comment: @lock Sorry, but clearly I can't investigate how you're pushing tarball
updates to other machines or what might be matter on the failing ones.
This is the standard macro for the job, and you have a site-local problem.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, after some investigations I have the answer.
First, in configure.ac I must set the language I use:

```
AC_LANG([C])
AC_LANG([C++])
```

Then, there is already an autoconf macro that checks for C++11 support in the C++ compiler: [AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html).

So, following this link: https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Local-Macros.html,
I have to create a m4 folder and put the macro definition inside. The best way  to proceed is to only download the more general [ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.html) file (and not ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4).
So, always in configure.ac I write:

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
```

and

```
m4_include([m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx.m4])
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX(11, noext, mandatory)
```

and Voilà.
Everything is OK, at least on the machine I've tested.